# Another match vector ASP

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, type-mismatch

Hello My problem is I have a globally declared array and go through some function changes the value of this, then I want to save the value of the array, call the function and return the array of values ​​that will put tenia.I example:

dim array1, array2

array1 (0) = 5 
array1 (1) = 6

array2 = array1

SomeFuncion call ()

array1 = array2

SomeFuncion function () 
array1 (0) = 8 
array1 (1) = 6 
end function

When I do this tells me that no mismatch

thank you very much

Comment: Can you explain the result you are looking for?  The last sentence doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim array1, array2

array1 (0) = 5 array1 (1) = 6
array2 = array1

call SomeFuncion  ()

array1 = array2

function SomeFuncion () 
array1 (0) = 8 
array1 (1) = 6 
end function
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't know much about this problem, but this answer came up on the "low quality posts" feed for review - mainly because there's just code and no explanation. It's generally considered a good idea to explain how your solution solves the Original Poster's problem. Mainly because lots of newbies come trawling through the web and find a solution here and if they don't understand how the solution works then they can't figure out whether the fix might also apply to their issue. So it's always good to explain it, even if it's obvious to more advanced programmers :)